# Hyperledger Composer: How to use card to call composer REST services

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-explorer

I build small business network on my local using Hyperledger composer.
I also created few cards for participant by following [this](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org) url.

Now I have to call different transactions on this blockchain by calling  REST services which are exposed via composer REST Server. But those transactions should have been called by respective participants only.

How can I call those services using earlier created cards from my Browser/Mobile app? Or card has nothing to do with services access? Then why we need to create cards for particpants?

Answer (score 1):

you will need to enable Multi-user mode and use Authentication as described above -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html

A full tutorial is already available here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest showing how you take those cards you created via CLI, and how to export those with credentials set, in preparation for importing into a client REST API (ie the user's browser, that's interacting with the auth-protected REST APIs). It shows how you can use different cards (and therefore diff blockchain identities, per the tutorial), to perform transactions on the business network, that is exposed via the protected REST APIs in the tutorial example.

Comment: Thanks Paul for reply. Google_oauth2 section looks promising. I have to try out those steps. Will let you know the result

Answer (score 0):

one way would be to create a rest api, using *composer-rest-api*. If you do this, you will notice that it asks you to specify which card you want to use. It will then use this card to interrogate you network, find out what assets, participants and transactions you have and it will generate all the endpoints required to interact with your ledger. This means that this api will connect via the identity you used to create the network card initially.

So :

1. you create a network card
2. you create a rest api against it.
3. your client app can now use this api to talk to your network.

now, the article you linked implements a certain scenario.

you have 1 network admin.
this admin creates admin identities, one for each org in the network.
these new admins can now issue new identities for their respective org.

there are more things you can do depending on your strategy.

examples would be here: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/enabling-multiuser

I suggest you go through those and select whatever applies to your specific scenario

Comment: Thanks Andrei for your reply. I have already done Steps 1,2,3 you mentioned above. I tried to follow first link again. But it is not yet cleared. After using Passport Github, how to get token in REST API? It is mentioned that token should be access first from Web browser and passed to actual REST API which is practically not possible in case of mobile apps.